# Using data from a ROS node in a separate C++/Python program

Tags: rosnode, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose there is a user-defined ROS node. I make it publish to a topic. Now i want to use this data published to the topic as input to a C++/Python program. So how do I

1. make the node publish to a topic?
2. route the data from the topic as input to another separate C++/Python program?

Any reference/tutorial with concrete coding examples is sought.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202284/using-data-from-a-ros-node-in-a-separate-c++/python-program/) by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-03**:
Did I understand you right that you do not want to subscribe to this topic. Instead you want this data as a program parameter?

**Comment by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on 2015-02-03**:
yes. i have a c++ function and the node is reading sensor data and processing it. i need the outputted data from this node as input for my c++ function. will subscribing to the topic to which this node publishes work? i amn't sure.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2015-02-04**:
I guess that creating a subscriber node that executes your c++ function on callback should work... But I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

**Comment by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on 2015-02-04**:
Yes, I think i should combine my code to a subscriber code and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gustavovelascoh is right.

Create a subscriber node and call you function from this subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1